# How to connect WebCamStudio output to VLC media player (as an input)

Tags: video, vlc

I am a videographer and occupational therapist. I am willing to do webcasts of patients' leissure activities (drama, music, etc.) to improve their health.

In order to do this I want to have a good [RTMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Messaging_Protocol) streamer. The only such streamer that I found for Ubuntu was [VLC media player](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VLC_media_player). But its capacity to change a live video is low. [WebcamStudio](https://code.google.com/p/webcamstudio/) is sufficient. But it cannot stream an RTMP stream. So how do I connect WebCamStudio with VLC media player or stream RTMP with WebCamStudio?

Answer (score -1):

you can find an answer going to G+ WebcamStudio community here :

https://plus.google.com/communities/110329269823088092206

Karl.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.